# TF-IDF in python issue for attribute error

Tags: python, tf-idf

i did install the packages needed but i kept getting this error

here is my code

```
# df.names is from a dataset

documentA = df.name
documentB = df.name
bagOfWordsA=documentA.split('')
bagOfWordsB=documentB.split('')

uniqueWords = set(bagOfWordsA).union(set(bagOfWordsB))

numOfWordsA = dict.fromkeys(uniqueWords, 0)
for word in bagOfWordsA:
    numOfWordsA[word] += 1
numOfWordsB = dict.fromkeys(uniqueWords, 0)
for word in bagOfWordsB:`enter code here`
    numOfWordsB[word] += 1
```

the error says:

> Attribute Error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Please include to the full traceback error.

Comment: This link might help - https://researchdatapod.com/how-to-solve-python-attributeerror-series-object-has-no-attribute-split/